# WebStorm JavaScript code completion: difference between TypeScript community stubs and official libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, phpstorm, webstorm, code-completion

I'm new to developing with WebStorm and don't understand the difference between adding an original library with a global scope (e.g. *jquery.js*) either from the local file system or by downloading it via the Download button (from the *Official libraries* list) and adding a so-called *TypeScript community stub* for jquery (all via *Settings...* -> *Languages & Frameworks* -> *JavaScript* -> *Libraries*). Both give me code completion, but what is the difference and what is preferable?

And why TypeScript when we are dealing with JavaScript only?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of them, there is no principal difference. Typescript stubs are definition files for popular javascript libraries and frameworks. Please see http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/ - you may find this blog post helpful